# Not able to change global variable in function used for zsh prompt

Tags: zsh

I'm trying to build a zsh function that returns an output based on a time interval. Initially the "You're thirsty" condition is true, but after changing the variable `thirsty` through the command line and setting it to false, the initial if statement goes through, but the variable `thirsty` in it doesn't change the `global variable thirsty`. **Is there a way to modify the global variable `thirsty`?**

```
thirsty=
last_time=

drink_water() {
echo -n "$thirsty"

  if [[ $thirsty == false ]]; then
    last_time="$[$(date +%s) + 10]"
    thirsty=true
    echo -n "${last_time} $(date +%s) ${thirsty}"

  elif [[ $[last_time] -lt $(date +%s) ]]; then
    echo -n " You're thirsty"
  fi

}
```

Comment: (BTW, `echo -n` is actually bad form -- the [POSIX spec for `echo`](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/utilities/echo.html) labels behavior when `-n` is provided as implementation-defined, meaning different shells can do different things with `echo -n`. If you want something *guaranteed* to print your exact string with no newline, use `printf '%s' "string"`; see also the APPLICATION USAGE section of the aforementioned link).

Comment: Speaking directly to the question: **All shell variables are global, unless you explicitly flag them otherwise**. This is why the question needs an explicit reproducer -- code someone else can copy, paste and run unmodified to see the behavior for themselves.

Comment: I have another function `spaceship_prompt` that calls this function. And then in the end I have `PROMPT='$(spaceship_prompt)'`

Comment: You are saying it is timed, which means you have not shown us the code that is controlling the time.  Please update script.

Comment: Another function inside the same script?

Comment: @LakshayKalbhor, `$()` puts its contents in a subshell, meaning a separate process, so changes to variables in that process can't change variables elsewhere. Your problem isn't one of local-vs-global scope, but one of being aware of when your code is inadvertently creating subprocesses. Anyhow, right now, your question doesn't have **nearly** enough information to let folks answer it properly.

Comment: What I mean by a timed output is that the variable `last_time` stores the current time + 10 , the second if statement checks when the current time is greater than `last_time`.

Comment: last_time controls what happens in this function, but this function must be in some kind of loop elsewhere for it to get tested more than once ... where is that code.  Also, have you noticed that thirsty never gets set to false anywhere?

Comment: @grail This code is part of a zsh theme. In the end the prompt is set to display from the provided function `PROMPT='$(drink_water)'`. Since `thirsty` is a global variable, it can be set to false through the terminal.

Comment: @LakshayKalbhor, ...that's critical information to understanding your problem, and should have been included in the question when it was first asked.

Comment: thirsty is global to the script ... not to the terminal.  Even if you passed it to the script, the first line that says thirsty= will overwrite what is passed in.  Also, not sure why we are mixing bash and zsh.  Even if things are similar, tell people the language you are in, not what is close that they might understand.

Comment: @grail, as part of a theme, if the OP is loading it correctly, this is code that's been sourced into the OP's shell configuration. It's not part of a separate script, but being invoked in an interactive shell.

Comment: @CharlesDuffy, thanks for the information.  My bad LakshayKalbhor I was not up on some of the information.  I am curious though where the spaceship function has gone that was originally setting PROMPT.  As pointed out, the more layers you go down, the more stuff that is going to get lost coming back out of subshells

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Since your code is actually called from:

```
PROMPT='$(drink_water)'
```

...everything it contains is run in a subprocess spawned as part of this command substitution operation (`$()` is a "command substitution": It creates a new subprocess, runs the code given in that subprocess, and reads the subprocess's output). When that subprocess exits, changes to variables -- even global variables -- made within the subprocess are lost.

If you put your update code directly inside a `precmd` function, then it would be run before each prompt is printed but without a command substitution intervening. That is:

```
precmd() {
  local curr_time=$(date +%s) # this is slow, don't repeat it!
  if [[ $thirsty = false ]]; then
    last_time="$(( curr_time + 10 ))"
    thirsty=true
    PROMPT="$last_time $curr_time $thirsty"
  elif (( last_time < curr_time )); then
    PROMPT=" You're thirsty"
  fi
}
```

Of course, you can set your PROMPT with a command substitution, but **updates to variable state have to be done separately, *outside* that command substitution**, if they are to persist.

Comment: This seems to work well, but lets say I have a few other functions that produce some other different outputs for the `PROMPT`, then how do I go about setting `PROMPT` to the output of all those functions. Since this function explicitly adds an output to `PROMPT`.

Comment: That's, bluntly, outside the scope of this question.

Comment: That said, I'd suggest splitting your logic into separate functions from your view. That is, do the updates in one function that you call from your main shell, and generate the string for display from a separate function you call in a command substitution. **However**, that advice is provided on a "for what it's worth, no followup entertained" basis -- and any efforts to make this into a [chameleon question](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/43478/exit-strategies-for-chameleon-questions) will be frowned on.

Comment: Oh, anyhow your answer cleared my confusion, since I was believing that the problem was related to the scope. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

You can use [Zsh Hooks](https://zsh.sourceforge.io/Doc/Release/Functions.html#Hook-Functions).

Hooks avoid the issues of command substitution here because they run in the same shell, rather than a subshell.

```bash
drink_water_prompt=

thirsty=
last_time=
drink_water_gen_prompt() {
    drink_water_prompt="$thirsty"
    if [[ $thirsty == false ]]; then
        last_time="$[$(date +%s) + 10]"
        thirsty=true
        drink_water_prompt+="${last_time} $(date +%s) ${thirsty}"
    elif [[ $[last_time] -lt $(date +%s) ]]; then
        drink_water_prompt+=" You're thirsty"
    fi
}

autoload -Uz add-zsh-hook 
add-zsh-hook precmd drink_water_gen_prompt

PROMPT='${drink_water_prompt}'
```

These also allow more than one `precmd()` function.